# react-native fetch() cookie persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cookies, fetch-api

I'm new to using react-native and also the `fetch` api in javascript. I authenticate my app with a backend and after several refreshes in my ios simulator the app checks if it's authenticated with the backend on the initial loading and to my surprise, it is! This begs the question of where and what is persisting inside react-native and the `fetch` api?

Comment: Nothing should be persisting unless you're using AsyncStorage

Comment: @matt it's a bare bones react-native app.. I haven't used the AsyncStorage. Could this be a dev environment feature?

Comment: So you want to presist the token?

Comment: I do want it to persist, but I want to understand why it's doing it currently without any configuration.

Comment: I had a same problem and finally had to use AsyncStorage to save token and cookie and also used react-native-cookies to clear all cookies. eg: CookieManager.cearAll()

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`fetch` on React Native is implemented on top of native-level APIs and *differs slightly* from the [whatwg specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) and the well-known [github polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch). This means that when the actual HTTP request is made, it's made by the native networking stack on iOS or [OkHttp3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) on Android, and in each case, it's the underlying ObjC or Java code that handles and stores the cookies, away from your JS code.

Until [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/274c5c78c4933a09335fca0e2fdc266c80fe4017) of Nov 2015, cookies weren't properly persisted on Android at all, but since RN 0.16 they've been supported on both platforms regardless of the `credential` setting in your `fetch` calls. As a result, session cookies and the like work out-of-the-box, which can be disconcerting if you're not expecting anything to be persisted. If you need to manipulate cookies from your JS, have a look at [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies), which interacts with the underlying cookie stores.

Comment: Thanks for this information! Since you say that `fetch` should work out of the box, could you maybe think of a scenario where it would *not* use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` for some reason? (I have logged in in the native part of my app, and I was expecting to be able to use requests that require authentication as-is in the RN part)

Comment: I really don't know enough about `NSHTTPCookieStorage` or RN's cookie implementation on top of it to say for sure, but I suspect there's additional work to be done to access the cookies if you're logged in through native code.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it to work - the only thing I had to do was to update react & react-native, together with the corresponding Pods. Then, cookies worked out of the box. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Aside from react-native-cookies, is there anything as simple as `credentials: 'omit'` to remove the cookies for just one fetch?

Comment: i am unable to get "set-cookie" parameter in response headers in fetch api in android. in ios i am getting it for first time. how to get "set-cookie" every time i login in both android and ios. i used to achieve this in native ios by setting setHTTPShouldHandleCookies to NO. thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem and finally had to use AsyncStorage to save token and cookie and also used react-native-cookies to clear all cookies. eg: CookieManager.cearAll()

Comment: this needs to be a comment